# Trouble trying to modify instance variable python

Tags: python, numpy, class

I'm having a hell of a time trying to modify an instance variable. In the code that follows, `shuffle_phase()` is supposed to modify the `self.env` variable. (EDIT: Here's an example use, full code follows below).

```
env_ = # Some input...

morpher = EnvelopeMorpher(env_)
morpher.shuffle_phase(num_shifts=4)

# morpher() returns internal `env_`

print(env_ - morpher())
```

Expected output: Difference between original and shuffled array.

Actual output: 0's.

I suspect this has to do with some deep down detail of Python that I'm not familiar with. Halp?

EDIT: Full example to run yourself:

```
import numpy as np
import math

class EnvelopeMorpher:
    """
    Generate variations of spectral modulation based on a prototype cycle.
    """
    # TODO: log morphs/stats.
    def __init__(self, env: np.ndarray):
        assert env.ndim == 2
        self.env = env

    def shuffle_phase(self, num_shifts: int = 4):
        """
        Randomly shuffle each column.
        """

        all_shifts = np.linspace(0, 1, num_shifts, endpoint=False)
        num_frames, num_bins = self.env.shape

        for k in np.arange(num_bins):
            shift = np.random.choice(all_shifts)

            tmp = self.env[:, k]
            tmp = self.roll(tmp, shift)

            self.env[:, k] = tmp

    def __call__(self):
        return self.env

    @staticmethod
    def roll(in_, shift):
        """
        Circular shift array using linear interpolation, where 0 <= `shift` < 1
        """
        num_samples = in_.size
        shift_samples = int(num_samples * shift)
        shift_fraction = shift_samples % 1

        out_ = np.zeros(num_samples)

        if shift_samples == 0:
            out_ += in_
        elif shift_fraction == 0:
            out_ += np.roll(in_, shift_samples)
        else:
            out_ += (1 - shift_fraction) * np.roll(in_, math.floor(shift_samples))
            out_ += shift_fraction * np.roll(in_, math.ceil(shift_samples))

        return out_

env_ = np.random.rand(50, 100)

morpher = EnvelopeMorpher(env_)
morpher.shuffle_phase(num_shifts=4)

# This will print 0's, but it shouldn't.
print(env_ - morpher())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get an error when doing `self.env[:, k] = tmp` with any inputs. Ideally, readers would need actual inputs/outputs, to see if that is the culprit. A minimal example of `__call__` working OK would be:

```
class EnvelopeMorpher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.env = 1
    def shuffle_phase(self):
        self.env = 2
    def __call__(self):
        return self.env
```

```
>>> morpher=EnvelopeMorpher()
>>> morpher()
1
>>> morpher.shuffle_phase()
>>> morpher()
2
```

So I don't suspect it is the structure of your code but perhaps one of these two lines:

```
num_frames, num_bins = self.env.shape

self.env[:, k] = tmp
```

Do you have sample inputs of the `env` from numpy that can be tested with?

### Update

it appears this is due to how your functions mutate the data. I'm not too familiar with the `np` methods so I can't comment specifically on which functions mutate the data and which don't (maybe a numpy expert can provide a better answer here), but the reason appears related to how it's mutating the data passed to it.

Here is an example with and without a copy of the data:

```
from copy import copy
env_ = np.random.rand(50, 100)
morpher = EnvelopeMorpher(copy(env_))
morpher.shuffle_phase(num_shifts=4)
print("With copy")
print(env_ - morpher())

env_ = np.random.rand(50, 100)
morpher = EnvelopeMorpher(env_)
morpher.shuffle_phase(num_shifts=4)
print("Without copy")
print(env_ - morpher())
```

```
With copy
[[ 0.          0.42362356  0.         ... -0.47365974  0.
  -0.15246997]
 [ 0.          0.19527261  0.         ...  0.44446104  0.
   0.12862735]

Without copy
[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
```

Or, even easier, in your `__init__` you can add a copy:

```
def __init__(self, env: np.ndarray):
    assert env.ndim == 2
    self.env = copy(env)
```

Comment: Agreed, I'll post a full example now so you can run it.

Comment: @MaxHenry updated, hope it's helpful. Sorry I don't know too much about numpy so can't be of more help. The code looks good though, nice work!

Comment: Wow, that's it. I had a suspicion it had something to do with `copy`. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @MaxHenry cool, can add in `self.env = copy(env)` to the `__init__` and it should fix it too.